# css border color stay the same as background, but I want it to change when mouse hovering

Tags: jquery, css, border, mouseover

I have a table. Intially, the border is white , and each cell has different background color. 
And I have a css class called highlight, `addClass("highlight")` will be fired.

**Highlightclass:**

```
table tr.highlight{
    height: 80px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF
}
```

For the easyness, I have only copied parts of html and JS to JSFiddle, but keep all the CSS, so please ignore some css if they seem not relevant.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("table tr").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("highlight")

    });

});
```

**Hover seems working, but unhover is not working at moment.**

Apparently, the height seems to increase by `80px`, but the border color of top and bottom is not changing. 
If it is changing, then the mouseovered tr will be standing out.

Does anyone know why?

http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/buaqnLyb/

Comment: i think its a typo instead of `removeClss` its `removeClass`

Comment: Simple typographical error. Check your console, that method doesn't exist and will fire errors. Learning proper debugging is a must when attempting to be a developer. [Here's an excellent write-up using Chrome's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: This could be done using only CSS table tr.highlight:hover

Comment: @Kartikeya, thanks for pointing my typo out, it works now. But the border issue still hasn't resolved yet.

Comment: Is it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/buaqnLyb/4/). what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using only CSS.

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/buaqnLyb/4/)

```
table tr:hover td{ /*Removed highlight class and added :hover*/
    height: 80px;
    border-top: 5px solid red; /*changed the border color*/
    border-bottom: 5px solid red
}
```

Comment: It is working. But if I can apply red to border, and why not WHITE? Why white is not working, but other colors?

Comment: @MatildaYiPan white works but you can't see the difference bcz background is also white

Comment: @MatildaYiPan: I have added both demos in my answer..check that

Comment: @Tushar, Thx for pointing out! White works as well! So, my question is why we have to include TR?

Comment: Giving border to tr create browser compatibility issues, so on hover of tr we can target all child td.

Answer (score 0):

**$("table tr td") selector in JS file  and ' .highlight' in CSS file are the changes needed**

**Look at the following fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/abhi47/c7ue3gfm/

**You have to include td also in the select parameter**

You can use toggleclass instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("table tr td").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
});
```

Simple and Easy

Get more info here http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
```

instead of adding and removing class.

**OR**

it should be easily done using css

```
table tr:hover td{
//your style 
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz0wneq7/)

[**WHITE COLOR DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz0wneq7/1/) //*not recommended bcz background is also white*

Comment: thx for pointing it out in the answer above, my question is : why we have to include TR in the selector? Initially, I want to highlight tr, so that's why I thought we only need tr as selector.

Comment: @MatildaYiPan tr selects the row...!!! you need borders when you hover over any rows..!! that's it :) :)